# Unable to push to github with EGIT

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I have been trying to configure Eclipse (Oxygen) to be able to push to a repository on github, but to no avail. I have been trying many different configurations and using the command line, TortiseGit and Atlassian Sourcetree. I have had varying levels of success with  all the others, but not with EGIT on Eclipse. I can clone the repo and import it. I can pull changes from it. But when go to push I always get the same problem, a "Not authorized" error. I have tried using _netrc, ssh keys, and passwords, all to no avail. I have tried following the instruction on all of the other questions of a similar nature I could find on stackoverflow, also with no joy. I don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [EGit push upstream](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Push_Upstream) section, using https, and entering your GitHub username and password, using an https (not ssh) URL:

```
https://github.com/<yourUsernameOnGitHub>/<yourRepo>
```

Make sure 2FA is not activated (or you would need a personal token) and that your password does not include any special characters.

Make sure you are pushing to a repo that you own.

Double-check if you have a git credential helper:

```
git config credential.helper.
```

If you see manager, open your [Windows Credential Manager](https://www.dotnetcatch.com/2017/08/08/use-multiple-github-accounts-on-windows-cli/):

[image: https://i2.wp.com/www.dotnetcatch.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/image_thumb.png?resize=644%2C397&ssl=1]

See if you had an entry in there with older credentials:

[image: https://i2.wp.com/www.dotnetcatch.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/image_thumb-1.png?resize=240%2C151&ssl=1]

You could delete them and try again.