# TFS: Git push fails on server but not locally

Tags: git, tfs, build, azure-devops

I have [TFS server with a GIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/overview?view=vsts) repository, and I want to execute a tool over the data in the repo and generate documentation.
I tried everything step by step in my local machine, in the server, and with a build in TFS.

1. git clone https://ale:pass1@tfsserver.com/tfs/Prd_Development/Develop/_git/ACSF_APEX_API_Docu -b develop
2. Execute the tool that generates files and copies it to the repo path
3. git add
4. git commit -am "mycommit"
5. git push

In my local machine everything and directly in the server works properly but in a TFS build, when I want to push the changes I get this error

```
C:\Users\ale\Documents\ACSF_APEX_API_Docu>git push origin develop
Counting objects: 6241, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3420/3420), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6241/6241), 1.73 MiB | 2.76 MiB/s, done.
Total 6241 (delta 3732), reused 4640 (delta 2598)
error: RPC failed; HTTP 401 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 401
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

But I realized that if I only add a few files I can perform the push.

I have read many post with the same or similar issue but all the solutions are not working in my case:

[postbuffer:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842687/the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-while-git-cloning) I raised the buffer but still not working. Anyways it's working on my local machine, so I think the buffer is not the problem.

[remote origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48362538/git-push-doesnt-work-but-git-pull-does) Also I checked that and the remote origin is set properly (also I clone the repository so it's Ok). Also in this post are talking about Windows Credentials. In my server are not set, so I also tried setting my credentials with no success.

[Wrong user password](https://github.com/gogs/gogs/issues/5089) Also checked, but discarded because I'm able to clone the repo

I can't understand what's going on because in my local machine works perfect but not in the TFS server

TY guys, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly, that your origin is cloned via HTTP(S)? Have you any other access protocol to the repository?

Comment: With http, git clone

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544142/git-error-rpc-failed-result-22-http-code-401-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-u

Comment: Seems you do not have a permission to commit to the remote repository.

Comment: Im able to perform a commit from my local machine with the same user Im using in the server.

The possible duplicated is one of the post I referenced and is not working in my case, I tried all mentioned in that post

Comment: Yes, you can commit to your local copy of the repository, because that is how Git works - it is a decentralized system. You cannot push, because you (presumably) do not have a permission to create commits on the remote end (tfsserver.com)

Comment: Sorry I mean push, I can push from my local machine to the git repo in TFS. That's why I cant understand what's going on, I can push from my local but not from the TFS server. Using the same user

Comment: Are the repository and the tool on the same server? If so, you can clone it directly on the filesystem.

Comment: Yes. 
I did many test and I think it should be something related to the number of objects(not files) Im trying to push 6241. Because if i try to push 3 objects (one file) it works

Comment: @AleXis can you pus changes to TFS git repo now?

Comment: Not yet. I 'm trying to do it with ssh. Because I cant figure out why it's not working with http

Comment: @AleXis Have you also cloned the TFS git repo to the TFS server before executing git push?

Comment: Yes, as I said in the post, first I clone the repo in the tfs server without problem, then I add many files to the repo, then commit, and then push. The push only fails when there are a lot files (Writing objects: 100% (6241/6241), 1.73 MiB | 2.76 MiB/s, done.) and  "git config --global http.postBuffer 1048576000" is not working in my case

Answer (score 0):

If the 'remote' (actually, it is better to call it a bare repository) repository is on the same machine, you might be able to clone it directly on the filesystem by `git clone <PATH>`. This will get around any possible issues connected with RPC.

Otherwise, I would recommend setting up OpenSSH (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=vsts).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll try this way